# Xamarin MvvmCross 3.5 What package should be added newly?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I updated Xamarin Mvvmcross 3.2.2 project to 3.5 for Unified API support.
Mvvmcross.HotTuna 3.5 package is added in project.
So there are Mvvmcross.HotTuna.CrossCore and Mvvmcross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries packages can be seen under Package folder.
But cannot find binding assemble, so "using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding;" is not resolved.
And MvxTouchSetup is also not resolved
The project worked well with Mvvmcross3.2.2.
Now what other nuget packages should be added in the project?

Comment: make sure you update your project to xamarin ios unified as well.

Comment: already updated. but no success.

Comment: Stuart, should i add new package from nuget library?

Answer (score 2):

No package is added newly.

- The 3.5 libraries package has been updated to include the new `MvvmCross.Touch.dll` for `lib\Xamarin.iOS10\` - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/nuspec/MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries.3.0.1.nuspec#L72
- The 3.5 crosscore package has bee update to include the new `MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.dll` for `lib\Xamarin.iOS10\` - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/nuspec/MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore.3.0.1.nuspec#L91

If the update isn't working for you:

- read the advice on http://kerry.lothrop.de/unified-api-for-xamarin-ios/ about how to update the unified
- check you have updated your own project to Xamarin iOS unified
- check you have up-to-date nuget installed
- clean, rebuild, swear and retry until it all works

Comment: The problem is the assembles under Xamarin.iOS10 folder are not added in the project references automatically after migration project to Unified API. Is there any way the project reference Xamarin.iOS10 folder libraries or should I add the assembles in the project manually?

Comment: I've had a similar problem. Turns out the project wasn't migrated successfully. Are you sure yours did? Quickest way to know is if monotouch is still referenced instead of Xamarin.iOS

you can also check the product ids [you can find on Xamarin's guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating_ios_apps/)